# Highlight currently working on code in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

Is there a way to highlight a section of code you are working on in PhpStorm? I'm working in multiple lengthly files, and I sometimes lose my place while scrolling through some of the larger files, and was wondering if there is a way to mark or highlight code so you can find your place quicker?

Comment: Do you mean bookmarks? https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2012/11/navigate-your-code-with-bookmarks/

Comment: Excellent, yes, that will work!